# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried to run this code below

```
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing import image

fnames = sorted([os.path.join(train_cats_dir, fname) for
             fname in os.listdir(train_cats_dir)])

img_path = fname[3]

img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(150, 150))
```

However, I got the error like this.

```
In [15]: img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(150, 150))
Traceback (most recent call last):

Input In [15] in <cell line: 1>
img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(150, 150))

File C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py:313 in load_img
return image.load_img(path, grayscale=grayscale, color_mode=color_mode,

File C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py:113 in load_img
with open(path, 'rb') as f:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.'
```

The error occurred when I run the last line img

I'm using tensorflow 2.8.0 and spyder from anaconda3

Thanks

Comment: Note: you don't need to pass a list comprehension to `sorted`. You can elide the brackets and pass a generator expression.

Comment: can you try this? fnames = sorted([join(train_cats_dir,f) for f in listdir(train_cats_dir) if isfile(join(train_cats_dir, f))]) , and remember to import os.path.join and isfile and os.listdir, I think your code is trying to get parent path or folder path too, with this script it should process file only

Comment: Yes I've tried the above one, but it still gives me same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out what is the exact problem of it (Maybe version issue I believe), but I changed the code like below and it worked well.

```
import keras.utils

fnames = sorted([os.path.join(train_cats_dir, fname) for
             fname in os.listdir(train_cats_dir)])

img_path = fnames[3]

img = keras.utils.load_img(img_path, target_size=(150, 150))
```

Importing `keras.utils` only solved it.